# Angular ui-grid double click row to open pop-up for editing a row

Tags: angularjs

**VERSION:**

I am using Angular ui-grid version 3.0.0-RC.18 (http://ui-grid.info/).

**PROBLEM**

I want to implement a double-click event in an ui-grid table. In particular, I want to open a modal pop-up when double-clicking at a row.

I tried to use a ng-dblclick directive inside the rowTemplate definition as is suggested at https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/2228 , but 'dblclick' event is never fired.

Nevertheless, I found a solution, but using a directive created by my own. Can I do it better, without creating a directive?

Any comment would be appreciated.

**CODE:**

My code at the Controller is as follows:

```
$scope.onDblClick = function(row) {
    var url = '//google.com';
    $window.open(url, "_blank", "height=600,width=800,toolbar=no,location=no,menubar=no,titlebar=no");
}

// Define the New Conflicts Simulation GRID behavior
$scope.myGridOptions = {
    showFooter: false,
    enableSorting: true,
    multiSelect: false,
    enableFiltering: true,     
    enableRowSelection: true, 
    enableSelectAll: false,
    enableRowHeaderSelection: false,  
    enableGridMenu: true,
    noUnselect: true,
    onRegisterApi: function (gridApi){
        $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
    },
    rowTemplate: "<div ng-dblclick=\"onDblClick(row)\" ng-repeat=\"(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.colDef.name\" class=\"ui-grid-cell\" ng-class=\"{ 'ui-grid-row-header-cell': col.isRowHeader }\" ui-grid-cell dbl-click-row></div>"            

}
```

(Where dbl-click-row indicates I am using the dblClickRow directive)

My code at the View is as follows:

```
<div id="myGrid" ui-grid="myGridOptions" ui-grid-selection ui-grid-resize-columns class="gridTable" ></div>
```

My code at the Directive is as follows:

```
var angularStartDirectives = angular.module('angularStart.directives', []);     

angularStartDirectives.directive('dblClickRow', ['$compile', '$parse',  function($compile, $parse) {
  return {
    priority : -190, // run after default uiGridCell directive
    restrict : 'A',
    scope : false,

    compile: function($element, attr) {

        // Get the function at ng-dblclick for ui-grid
        var fn = $parse(attr['ngDblclick'], /* interceptorFn */ null, /* expensiveChecks */ true);

        return function ngEventHandler(scope, element) {

            element.on('dblclick', function(event) {

              var callback = function() {

                if ($scope.gridApi.grid.selection.lastSelectedRow)
                {
                    fn($scope, {$event:event, row: $scope.gridApi.grid.selection.lastSelectedRow.entity });
                }
              };

              $scope.$apply(callback);

            }
        )};

    }

    };
} ]);
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well, my question was answered at Github:

https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/2228#issuecomment-71912850

My mistake was not to use external-scopes, and try to solve the problem with ng-dblclick only.

The code should be like this:

At the Controller:

```
$scope.gridHandlers = { 

    onDblClick : function(row) {
        var url = '//google.com';
        $window.open(url, "_blank", "height=600,width=800,toolbar=no,location=no,menubar=no,titlebar=no");
   }
}

$scope.myGridOptions = {
    showFooter: false,
    enableSorting: true,
    multiSelect: false,
    enableFiltering: true,     
    enableRowSelection: true, 
    enableSelectAll: false,
    enableRowHeaderSelection: false,  
    enableGridMenu: true,
    noUnselect: true,
    onRegisterApi: function (gridApi){
        $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
    },
    rowTemplate: "<div ng-dblclick=\"getExternalScopes().onDblClick(row)\" ng-repeat=\"(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.colDef.name\" class=\"ui-grid-cell\" ng-class=\"{ 'ui-grid-row-header-cell': col.isRowHeader }\" ui-grid-cell ></div>"            

}
```

At the View:

```
<div id="myGrid" ui-grid="myGridOptions" ui-grid-selection ui-grid-resize-columns class="gridTable" external-scopes="gridHandlers"></div>
```

#### Update for ui-grid v3.0.0-rc.21:

Considering that externalScopes is no longer supported, and now appScopeProvider rules.

In the view:

```
<div id="myGrid" ui-grid="myGridOptions" ui-grid-selection ui-grid-resize-columns class="gridTable" ></div>
```

In the controller:

```
$scope.myGridOptions = {
    showFooter: false,
    enableSorting: true,
    multiSelect: false,
    enableFiltering: true,     
    enableRowSelection: true, 
    enableSelectAll: false,
    enableRowHeaderSelection: false,  
    enableGridMenu: true,
    noUnselect: true,
    onRegisterApi: function (gridApi){
       $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
    },
    appScopeProvider: { 
        onDblClick : function(row) {
           var url = '//google.com';
           $window.open(url, "_blank", "height=600,width=800,toolbar=no,location=no,menubar=no,titlebar=no");
         }
    },
    rowTemplate: "<div ng-dblclick=\"grid.appScope.onDblClick(row)\" ng-repeat=\"(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.colDef.name\" class=\"ui-grid-cell\" ng-class=\"{ 'ui-grid-row-header-cell': col.isRowHeader }\" ui-grid-cell ></div>"
}
```

Here is my example at Plnkr using a modal popup (done with angular-ui-bootstrap):

http://plnkr.co/edit/cq7s9lKn90xTVgNxIC6b?p=preview

Note that if you use a newer version of ui-bootstrap, you will need to rename $modal in the above plunkr to $uibModal.

Comment: I found converting the rowTemplate from ng-grid to ui-grid to be a problem.  This finally worked for me once I realized I had a typo on the function name.

Comment: I've been trying this for hours and I can't get it to work. One part of the challenge is that I don't know what's part of the solution and what's irrelevant. Any chance you could remove some of the irrelevant parts?

Comment: I actually ended up figuring it out myself. [Details in this answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30226543/199712)

Comment: Is it possible to edit those values in external scope ?

Comment: appScopeProvider row clicks working well but another single click button in cellTemplate(in a column) is not working now. Any possible solution?

Answer (score 2):

I've used Aquiles solution and reduced scopes just to appSCope, see [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/gI7t0Smt98ZfBRe4Ewbn?p=preview).

I've rewrite code to showInfo becomes to $scope:

```
$scope.showInfo = function(row) {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      controller: 'InfoController',
      templateUrl: 'ngTemplate/infoPopup.html',
      resolve: {
        selectedRow: function () {                    
            return row.entity;
        }
      }
   });

   modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
     $log.log('modal selected Row: ' + selectedItem);
   }, function () {
     $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
  });
}
```

At gridOptions just used appScope:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {

   showFooter: true,
   enableSorting: true,
   multiSelect: false,
   enableFiltering: true,     
   enableRowSelection: true, 
   enableSelectAll: false,
   enableRowHeaderSelection: false,
   selectionRowHeaderWidth: 35,  
   noUnselect: true,
   enableGridMenu: true,
   columnDefs: [{displayName:'Name',field:'name'},{displayName:'Gender',field:'gender'},{displayName:'Company',field:'company'}],
   rowTemplate: "<div ng-dblclick=\"grid.appScope.showInfo(row)\" ng-repeat=\"(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.colDef.name\" class=\"ui-grid-cell\" ng-class=\"{ 'ui-grid-row-header-cell': col.isRowHeader }\" ui-grid-cell></div>"
};
```

Too, I added columnDefs to show that rowTemplate don't interfere with grid rendering.

Answer (score 0):

The solution with custom rowTemplate works fine. I've found a more elegant solution which adds the event to the 'ui-grid/ui-grid-row' template:

```
rowTemplate : $templateCache.get('ui-grid/ui-grid-row').replace("<div ", "<div ng-dblclick=\"grid.appScope.onDblClick(row, $event)\" "),
```

The double click event handler would be something like this:

```
$scope.onRowDblClick = function (row) {
    if (row && row.entity) {
        //insert your custom code
    }
};
```

You'll have to add the dependency to $templateCache in your controller.