# Angular UI Grid click row

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have a list of items in an [Angular UI Grid](http://ui-grid.info/). When I click a row, I want to be taken to a different page. (In other words, each row in the grid will be a link.)

I imagine this must be a very common desire, although I haven't really seen any documentation on how to do it. What's a good way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I figured out the answer myself. Here's my controller (ES6):

```
'use strict';

class TrackingRecordsCtrl {
  constructor($scope) {
    // The content of this template is included
    // separately 
    $scope.gridOptions = {
      rowTemplate: 'app/components/tracking-record/grid-row.html',
    };

    // This function is referenced from the row's template.
    // I'm just console.logging the row but you can of
    // course do anything you want with it.
    $scope.gridRowClick = row => {
      console.log(row);
      // or maybe $location.path(row.url)?
    };

    $scope.gridOptions.data = {
      // This of course can't just be an empty object.
      // Chances are you already have something defined
      // for gridOptions.data.
    };
  }
}

TrackingRecordsCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];

export default TrackingRecordsCtrl;
```

And here's my row template (Jade):

```
.ui-grid-cell(
  ng-repeat='(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.colDef.name'
  ng-class="{ 'ui-grid-row-header-cell': col.isRowHeader  }"
  ui-grid-cell=''
  ng-click='grid.appScope.gridRowClick(row)'
)
```

And as a bonus, here's my stylesheet (SCSS). I thought it would make sense to highlight the row under the cursor and use a `pointer` cursor to make it clearer that the rows are clickable.

```
.ui-grid-row {
  cursor: pointer;

  &:hover .ui-grid-cell {
    background-color: #CCC;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 16):

Here is the solution i used. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32815458/2452630

```
        yourCtrl.gridOptions = {
        enableFiltering: true,
        enableHiding : false,
        enableSorting: true,
        appScopeProvider : yourCtrl,
        rowTemplate: '<div ng-click="grid.appScope.doSomething(row)" ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid" class="ui-grid-cell" ng-class="col.colIndex()" ui-grid-cell></div>',
    };

    yourCtrl.doSomething = function(row) {
        alert("lala");
    }
```

Comment: Incredible having to do this to add a row click handler

Answer (score 12):

The question as I understand it: clicking a row in an Angular UI Grid should result in navigation to a related page (i.e. the row should behave like a link). For example, a list of contacts are displayed in the grid, and clicking on a row takes you to a contact details page.

Kudos to the OP for answering his own question in an innovative way. However,  I prefer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30224300/896265) as it does not require the creation of a custom row template. I have fleshed it out a bit more, as the OP did not seem satisfied with Kathir's example.

Firstly, understand that the following code sets up a listener function for whenever the row.isSelected property changes:

```
gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope,function(row){
        //Do something when a row is selected
      });
```

I.e. whenever a row is clicked, this function will be called. Note the `row` parameter passed to the function which can be used to access the entity that the row represents. For example, if a row represented a contact entity, then you could access the `contactId` property of the row/entity that was selected. The following example uses UI Router's `$state` service to navigate to a contact details page passing the `contactId` obtained from the `row.entity` property:

```
this.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function (gridApi) {
                //set gridApi to controller property
                this.gridApi = gridApi;
                gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope, function (row) {
                    $state.go("contact.details.view", {contactId: row.entity.contactId});
                });
            }
```

Note that the `$scope` object is required to be passed in, even if you are using `Controller as` syntax. Refer to this [article](http://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/) about `Controller as` syntax.

For a full example using Typescript (file references omitted for brevity):

```
"use strict"
export class ContactsCtrl {

    title: string;
    contacts: interfaces.IContact[] = [];
    gridAPI: any;
    gridOptions: any = {
        enableFullRowSelection: true,
        enableRowSelection: true,
        multiSelect: false,
        enableRowHeaderSelection: false,
        data: "vm.contacts",
        columnDefs: [
            { field: "contactId", displayName: "Contact ID", width: 100 },
            { field: "name", displayName: "Contact Name" }            ]
    }

    static $inject = ["$scope", "$state"];
    constructor(private $scope : ng.IScope, private $state : ng.ui.IStateService) {
        this.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function (gridApi) {
            //set gridApi on scope
            this.gridApi = gridApi;
            gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope, function (row) {
                $state.go("contact.details.view", {contactId: row.entity.contactId});
            });
        }
    }
}
angular.module("app.contacts").controller("ContactsCtrl", contacts.controllers.ContactsCtrl);
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have just came across to your answer and I think you cannot call `$state` in that way, first thing the variable is private and so you need to use `this.$scope` and then because `this` is binded to `gridApi` doesn't it?

Answer (score 4):

```
  $scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function( gridApi ) {
    $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
       gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope,function(row){
        var msg = 'row selected ' + row.isSelected;
        //Open your link here.
      });
  };
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/EO920wsxuqr3YU8931GF?p=preview

Comment: Hmm, I don't see how this answers the question. I can't click on any row in your Plunker, and if there's a way to adjust your custom template to result in a clickable row, it's not obvious to me. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Sorry, I re-read my question and realized it might be unclear. What I want is for each row of my grid to be a link that takes me to a different page. (I also updated my question to be clearer.)

Comment: check the new plnkr and see

Comment: That's closer but I'm not sure that it seems like an acceptable solution to me. A row selection doesn't seem relevant to a row simply being clicked.

Comment: Presumably the selected row contains some information about what you want to happen. The api.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged event simply becomes where you perform whatever action you wish (in the questioner's case a view change) and get the row data to accomplish that. It's the UI-Grid eqivalent of onClick.