# Typescript with angularjs ui.grid

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am using Typescript with angular js 1.4.7 and ui.grid version 3.0.7 and very new to these technologies.
I have created a very simple grid comprising of two fields. The third column would be the delete button.
How can i get the row details of the row whose delete button has been clicked ?

Also, please let me know if there are any good to read articles of books on angularjs with typescript.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28201723/angular-ui-grid-double-click-row-to-open-pop-up-for-editing-a-row

Comment: Thanks Martin. I have already implemented the grid delete functionality. But the link you shared helped me understand a few more things. Thanks for the help.